# Changing of elements of array when passed as an index of another array

Tags: c, arrays, immutability

I am a rookie, and I hope this question is not a naive one!

I have the following function, where I use elements of one array as indices of another. However, despite my making no changes to the former, I see that the elements are being modified. The code is as follows:

```
void convert_to_bitmap(int n_shapes, int sizex, int sizey,
                       int ll_x[n_shapes], int ll_y[n_shapes],
                       int ur_x[n_shapes], int ur_y[n_shapes],
                       int shapes_ll_bitmap[sizex][sizey],
                       int shapes_ur_bitmap[sizex][sizey] )
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n_shapes; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, %d, %d, %d check1\n", ll_x[i], ll_y[i], ur_x[i], ur_y[i]);

    }

    for (i = 0; i < n_shapes; i++)
    {
        shapes_ll_bitmap[ll_x[i]][ll_y[i]] = 1;
        shapes_ur_bitmap[ur_x[i]][ur_y[i]] = 1;

        printf("%d, %d, %d, %d check2\n", ll_x[i], ll_y[i], ur_x[i], ur_y[i]);
    }
}
```

And, the output shows that the first array has changed when I do so. Is there some way to keep it immutable?

Output:

```
0, 0, 0, 7 check1
0, 9, 0, 15 check1
1, 0, 1, 7 check1
1, 9, 1, 15 check1
2, 13, 2, 15 check1
2, 17, 2, 24 check1
2, 26, 2, 32 check1
0, 0, 0, 7 check2
0, 9, 0, 15 check2
1, 0, 1, 7 check2
1, 9, 1, 15 check2
1, 13, 2, 15 check2
2, 1, 2, 1 check2
1, 26, 2, 32 check2
```

This is how I invoke the function in main():

```
convert_to_bitmap(n_shapes, sizex, sizey, ll_x, ll_y, ur_x, ur_y, shapes_ll_bitmap, shapes_ur_bitmap);
```

And the declaration and initialization of the matrices in int main() is as follows:

```
int ll_x[n_shapes];
int ll_y[n_shapes];
int ur_x[n_shapes];
int ur_y[n_shapes];

int sizex;
int sizey;

int shapes_ll_bitmap[sizex][sizey];
int shapes_ur_bitmap[sizex][sizey]; 

for (i=0; i < sizex; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < sizey; j++)
    {
        shapes_ll_bitmap[i][j] = 0;
        shapes_ur_bitmap[i][j] = 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Thank you!

Edit:

Here's some self-contained code:

```
int main(void)
{   
    enum { MAX_SHAPES = 100000 };
    struct Rectangle rect_array[MAX_SHAPES];
    int n_shapes = read_shapes_rpt("shapes.rpt", MAX_SHAPES, rect_array);
    int i, j;

    float pitch_x = 0.044;
    float pitch_y = 0.042;

    float ll_x_flt[n_shapes];
    float ll_y_flt[n_shapes];
    float ur_x_flt[n_shapes];
    float ur_y_flt[n_shapes];

    int ll_x[n_shapes];
    int ll_y[n_shapes];
    int ur_x[n_shapes];
    int ur_y[n_shapes];

    int sizex;
    int sizey;

    int shapes_ll_bitmap[sizex][sizey];
    int shapes_ur_bitmap[sizex][sizey]; 

    for (i=0; i < sizex; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < sizey; j++)
        {
            shapes_ll_bitmap[i][j] = 0;
            shapes_ur_bitmap[i][j] = 0;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    if (n_shapes > 0)
    {
        transform_to_shape_bit_locations(n_shapes, rect_array, ll_x_flt, ll_y_flt, ur_x_flt, ur_y_flt, ll_x, ll_y, ur_x, ur_y, &pitch_x, &pitch_y, &sizex, &sizey);

        convert_to_bitmap(n_shapes, sizex, sizey, ll_x, ll_y, ur_x, ur_y, shapes_ll_bitmap, shapes_ur_bitmap);

        printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", n_shapes, sizex, sizey);
        /* Use the shapes that were read */
    }



    return 0;
}
```

My shapes.rpt file contained the following csv values:

```
1.408,529.237,1.43,529.523
1.408,529.597,1.43,529.883
1.452,529.237,1.474,529.523
1.452,529.597,1.474,529.883
1.496,529.777,1.518,529.883
1.496,529.957,1.518,530.243
1.496,530.317,1.518,530.564
```

Comment: The indexing you're doing looks fine... you're probably writing out of bounds on `shapes_ll_bitmap` or `shapes_ur_bitmap`, but it's hard to say for sure without knowing how you've set up the arrays or how big they are.  Check that you haven't reversed your x and y coordinates, also.

Comment: The matrices are both 3x33, so I haven't exceeded the dimensions. And since I have printed just before the second loop with the same use of X and Y coordinates, reversing them would have no effect on the fact that the array elements were changed, would it?

Comment: Show how you call this function and how the actual arguments are declared/initialized.

Comment: Can we see how you've declared or allocated the array, and how you call the function?  If the coordinates are backward or the dimensions are reversed when calling the function, you could easily access outside the array bounds.

Comment: You can also try to print the elements of the two bitmaps arrays both before and after the change.

Comment: @SulfoCyaNate: That's not enough. Post the declarations of the arrays in the caller. How is `shapes_ll_bitmap` declared?

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question description to include the invocation and declaration of arrays.

Comment: @SulfoCyaNate: How come `sizex` and `sizey` are uninitialized? Is this just partial code?

Comment: using `const` could help with keeping unwanted modifications from happening

Comment: @Isaiah: `const` will not prevent *this* sort of "magical" modifications from happening.

Comment: Yes, this is just partial code. I'm posting only a small part of my code, but if it helps, I 'm editing it to make it self-contained

Comment: @Isaiah: It is completely unclear what you mean by this. In function parameter list `int a[func_param]` is 100% equivalent to `int a[]` or `int *a` anyway.

Comment: as stated by @SulfoCyaNate, the variables sizex and sizey are not initialized, so they contain what ever trash happens to be on the stack at their locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variables `sizex` and `sizey` are left uninitialized. Which means that your matrices `shapes_ll_bitmap` and `shapes_ur_bitmap` have unpredictable size (the behavior is actually undefined).

Note that when you actually assign meaningful values to your your `sizex` and `sizey` later, it is already too late. The matrices are already declared with *indeterminate* sizes and that's final. Once the matrices are declared, any changes to the values of `sizex` and `sizey` will have no effect on the matrices.

Your matrices end up with some indeterminate size, which results in out-of-bounds access inside `convert_to_bitmap` function and destruction of unrelated memory values.

Comment: I initialize them in the transform_to_shape_bit_locations function, and when I print them out, I get the correct expected values.

Comment: @ SulfoCyaNate: That's too late. When you declare your matrices, the sizes are uninitialized. After that it is already too late to initialize the sizes.

Comment: You're being pretty charitable with the last 2 paragraphs; the whole program has undefined behaviour as a result of the attempt to declare the arrays with indeterminate size

Comment: @Matt McNabb: Maybe, but the whole ordeal is probably a consequence of that popular newbie misconception: people believe that changing size variable used in a VLA declaration will somehow retrospectively change the size of the already declared array (or turn indeterminate size into determinate one). It is not the first time I come across it. From this point of view, my last paragraph might be overly "charitable", but not the second one.